# Конвертация structure с виртуальными функциями в string, определение размера structure

Tags: c++

Данный код моделирует создание обьектов -> сериализация -> отправка по сети -> десириализация.

Object.h

```
#include <sstream>

struct IObject
{
public:
    virtual void Val1(int) = 0;
    virtual int Val1() = 0;

    virtual void Val2(double) = 0;
    virtual double Val2() = 0;

    virtual void Val3(long int) = 0;
    virtual long int Val3() = 0;

    virtual void ConvertToStream(std::stringstream&) = 0;
    virtual void ParseFromBuffer(char*) = 0;
    virtual std::size_t Size() = 0;
};

struct RawObject : public IObject
{
public:
    inline void ConvertToStream(std::stringstream& stream) override
    {
        stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&this->val1), sizeof(this->val1));
        stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&this->val2), sizeof(this->val2));
        stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&this->val3), sizeof(this->val3));
    }
    void ParseFromBuffer(char* buffer) override
    {
        char* next_var = buffer;

        this->val1 = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(next_var);
        next_var += sizeof(this->val1);

        this->val2 = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(next_var);
        next_var += sizeof(this->val2);

        this->val3 = *reinterpret_cast<long int*>(next_var);
    }
    std::size_t Size() override
    {
        return sizeof(this->val1) + sizeof(this->val2) + sizeof(this->val3);
    }
    void Val1(int val) override { this->val1 = val; }
    int Val1() override { return this->val1; }

    void Val2(double val) override { this->val2 = val; }
    double Val2() override { return this->val2; }

    void Val3(long int val) override { this->val3 = val; }
    long int Val3() override { return this->val3; }
private:
    int val1;
    double val2;
    long int val3;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

#include "Object.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::stringstream stream;

    int num_objects = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_objects; ++i)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<IObject> object_send = std::make_shared<RawObject>();

        object_send->Val1(1 + i);
        object_send->Val2(2.0 + i);
        object_send->Val3(3 + i);

        object_send->ConvertToStream(stream);
    }

    std::string objects_string = stream.str();

    std::array<char, 1000> buffer;

    std::copy(objects_string.begin(), objects_string.end(), &buffer[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < num_objects; ++i)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<RawObject> object_recv = std::make_shared<RawObject>();
        static std::size_t size_object = object_recv->Size();

        object_recv->ParseFromBuffer(&buffer[size_object * i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Если ли более правильное решение определения размера объекта чем sizeof(member var1) + .. + sizeof(member varN)? Можно ли определять sizeof(RawObject) - размер указателя на виртуальную таблицу функции? Как тогда определять размер vptr,ведь как я понимаю он зависит от разрядности системы?
2. Может есть какие-то предложения по улучшению функций ConvertToStream и ParseFromBuffer?

Comment: Вы пишете три отдельных поля - значит, их общую длину нужно смотреть именно как сумму. У всего объекта могут быть и vptr, и выравнивание, и прочие фокусы - словом, сумма длин полей не будет равна длине объекта. Но мне непонятно - зачем у вас в абстрактном классе заранее зашиты все эти `Val#`? Они же фактически навязывают структуру потомкам. А если вы захотите писать что-то со строками и `bool`, а не эти ваши `int` и иже с ним?

Comment: `size_object` должен в том или ином виде содержаться в полученном буфере. Кроме того, `ParseFromBuffer` помимо указателя должна принимать размер буфера и передвигать курсор по мере чтения.

Comment: @Harry предпологается, что некий контейнер содержит интерфейс IObject, который должен работать с разными объектами, например, RawObject, ProcessedObject, поэтому мне приходится в интерфейсе задавать все функции, потходящие для разных объектов.

Comment: Вот как раз потому что интерфейс должен работать с разными объектами - не нужна эта конкретизация в абстрактном классе. Что если у конкретного просто не будет такого поля? А он все равно должен его реализовывать... Вы же эти функции в самом абстрактном классе не используете.

Comment: @Harry А что делать тогда если мне нужна конкретное значение, а я его не могу получить через интерфейс? Нужно приводить к конкретному объекту?

Comment: Вообще-то да. Как вы будете получать конкретное значение из абстрактного класса, если в конкретном классе его, например, просто нет? Можно использовать другие варианты - типа объединения, но вообще это ерунда. Вы создаете абстрактный класс только как интерфейс для записи-чтения, вот он и должен заниматься только своими обязанностями...